# Sticky Footer at bottom of PAGE, not just bottom of WINDOW

Tags: css-position, sticky-footer

I have been searching online for a few days now trying to crack this:

My code approx layout:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
        <div id="top-header"></div>     <!-- This is a fixed position header -->
        <div id="content"></div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

I'm trying to make my footer so it works in the following two scenarios:

1) When there is little/no content the footer sits at the bottom of the screen (to avoid ugly/unprofessional-looking gaps)

2) When the content overfills the page (requiring a scrollbar), the footer is at the bottom of the PAGE (ie: is initially hidden until you scroll down).

**Unsuccessful FIX #1**
So far, I have tried using position:fixed, which works in scenario (1) but in scenario (2), the footer is always visible (in its fixed position at the bottom of the window), which I don't want. I only want to be able to see the footer when I scroll to the bottom.

**Unsuccessful FIX #2**
I then found a little more success by absolutely position the footer relative to the 'wrapper' div (which had a min-height:100%). In scenario (1) this worked fine! But when I tried scenario (2), the footer would appear absolutely at the bottom of the "window" but not the bottom of the "page" (or more specifically the 'wrapper' div). When I would then scroll down, the footer would move with the page and cut across the content - very strange! ...... It seems the problem is arising because the height of the 'wrapper' is relative to the window size (height:100%) and this varies in real-time as I change the window size. Is there a way I can state the height of the 'wrapper' div to be 100% of the 'page' rather than 100% of the 'window'? If you think there is a better method or need to see the source code, please let me know... I will happily provide.

I have posted this question because even after following several detailed instructions to fix it, and searching in the archived threads on this site, I have been unsuccessful. Any help would be most appreciated.

JMSSTKS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get the footer to stay at the bottom of a Web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page)